# Module federation and React Context hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

When using React `useContext` hooks, it currently requires an import from a component higher up in the tree to pass in the `Context` object. Say for example:

```
// index.jsx
export const MyContext = React.useContext('1')

export function MyApp(props){
  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value='1'>
        <ChildComponent />
    </MyContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

```
// ChildComponent.jsx
import {MyContext} from './index';

export function ChildComponent(props){
  const context = useContext(MyContext);
  return (<p> {context} </p>)
}
```

But if the child component is federated, it will be in a separate repo on its own, and cannot import from `'./index'`.

At the `MyApp` level, I can import the `ChildComponent` with:

`const ChildComponent= React.lazy(() => import('federatedApp/ChildComponent'))`

provided that within the Webpack config, the `federatedApp` is named as a remote, and the HTML doc includes the remote modules entry point .js. But how might I give `MyContext` to the remote `federatedApp`?

**Guess answer**: Would I need to separate the two components in `index.jsx` into two files and expose them both separately?